# directive won't manipulate the element properly if called on click event

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

[image]

I have a edit button directive that I would like to listen for click events.
I would like it to trigger the collapseHeader function I have made inside the directive during the click event.
The problem is when I try to manipulate the element it will only work outside the event listener.
Why is this happening? and what would I need to do to prevent it from happening?

```
    function link( scope, element, attrs ) {

        // will work here
        // collapseHeader();

        element.on( 'click', function () {
            // won't work here
            collapseHeader();
        } );

        function collapseHeader () {
            // both cases passes through here. But if called in the event listener, it won't successfully collapse my header
            var collapseEl = angular.element(  '.collapsible-header' );
            collapseEl.addClass( 'active' );
        }

    }

    var directive = {
        'restrict': 'A',

        'scope' : {
            'selectedModel' : '=',
            'viewModel'     : '='
        },

        'link': link
    };
```

My html file:

Add department location, this is where it should collapse

```
<ul class="collapsible z-depth-0" data-collapsible="accordion" watch>
    <li>
        <div id="unique-collapse" class="collapsible-header yellow darken-4 white-text"><i class="mdi-communication-location-on"></i>Add department location<i class="mdi-hardware-keyboard-arrow-down right no-margin"></i></div>
        <div class="collapsible-body white wrapper">
            <div class="row no-margin">
                <form novalidate name="vm.depLocationForm">
                    <div class="row">
                        <h5>Department Location Details</h5>
                        <input-field class="col l6 s12">
                            <input type="text" id="departmentCode" ng-model="vm.depDetails.depCode" required>
                            <label for="departmentCode">* Department Code</label>
                        </input-field>
                        <input-field class="col l6 s12">
                            <input type="text" id="departmentDesc" ng-model="vm.depDetails.depDesc" required>
                            <label for="departmentDesc">* Department Description</label>
                        </input-field>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row no-margin">
                        <button class="pink accent-2 btn-flat right waves-effect waves-light white-text" ng-click="vm.addDepartmentLocation()">Add</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
<br />
```

Department list, this is where I have the edit button directive on each element. If edit is clicked it should trigger collapseHeader() and successfully dropdown.

```
<ul class="collection user-collection collection-overflow">
    <li class="collection-item avatar" ng-repeat="department in vm.departmentLocations">
        <i class="circle initial-badge blue">{{department.initials}}</i>
        <span class="title">{{department.d_code}}</span>
        <p class="grey-text">
            <span>{{department.d_desc}} </span>
        </p>
        <div class="secondary-content">
            <!-- Dropdown Trigger -->
            <a class="" href="" data-activates="demoDropdown-{{department.d_id}}" dropdown data-hover="false">
                <i class="mdi-hardware-keyboard-control" href="#"></i>
            </a>

            <!-- Dropdown Structure -->
            <ul id="demoDropdown-{{department.d_id}}" class="dropdown-content">
                <!-- where directive should be called -->
                <li edit-admin  selected-model="department" view-model="vm"><a href=""><i class="mdi-editor-mode-edit"></i> Edit</a></li>
                <li><a href=""><i class="mdi-action-delete"></i> Delete</a></li>
            </ul>


        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I tried to console.log both instances and discovered that it still successfully added the "active" class but the problem when called in the event scope that it does not visually update.

Comment: Did you tried event.preventDefault(); inside the event?

Comment: Why don't think of `ng-class` here? by using one toggling flag in socpe

Comment: @PankajParkar because the element using this directive is a edit button. What I want to do is when I click this directive, it collapses the form which displays the form and data. This is why I have a selectedModel and viewModel in my scope.

Comment: tried @Fals but also did not work.

Comment: Using selector like angular.element(  '.collapsible-header' ) is just awfull. Cant know what you are selecting and from where. Besides this selector : http://plnkr.co/edit/hs4sT7km9yKpD1KBGPe6?p=preview It works ok.

Comment: @MoneceSolis creating plunkr with issue would be good to help..

Comment: it's somehow like this this http://plnkr.co/edit/e6NppaqrwORBgZlU9abB?p=preview in my original code im using controllerAs in my controller though. So might cause confusion. Sorry about that. @PankajParkar

Comment: @PetrAveryanov I created a plunker. Sadly my directive is not a child element of the collapsible header element.

Comment: Could not make my other dropdown to work in plunkr though. :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that it wasn't able to listen to changes like it usually should. I think the best solution for this problem was not to create this as a directive but into a factory, it helps me to avoid using $apply/$watch and is much more efficient. But to solve this problem in a directive approach. I must use scope().apply() into my element for it to be able to track changes into my element in the event listener scope. Must be because of jquery.

```
        function collapseHeader () {
            var collapseEl = angular.element(  '.collapsible-header' );
            collapseEl.addClass( 'active' );
            collapseEl.scope().$apply();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully I understand correctly. You can edit the element directly from the listener, try:

```
element.on( 'click', function () {
    //use element, not angular.element etc
    element.addClass( 'active' );
});

//function collapseHeader(){}
```

Alternatively, consider using of ng-click in the view.

```
<li edit-admin ng-click="collapseHeader()" selected-model="department"     
view-model="vm"><a href=""><i class="mdi-editor-mode-edit"></i> 
Edit</a></li>
```

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/g89PL3M8NePlN7fh0qN2 - I've created a plunker example of a way of doing this by broadcasting the click event. Although it would be confusing to track this in a larger application. For this type of problem I would use Petr Averyanov's example in the plunker example above - where the child has a reference to its parent.

Comment: Yep. the plnkr you just sent also works out. We have a similar approach to solve the problem, I just used scope.apply instead of watch. Thanks Nick!